# Jquery in django : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates, formset

For the life of me I can't figure out what's wrong with this code. It used to work in an earlier version and after I rearranged the javascript at the bottom of the page it just won't work properly. It keeps giving me this error:
[image]

The row where it throws the error is the following:
`$('.formset_row').formset({`

And this is [the jquery plugin](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset) that i used. This used to work perfectly until like yesterday when i probably touched something i shouldnt have.

```
    <!-- Select2 JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Semantic UI -->
    
   
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-u7e5khyithlIdTpu22PHhENmPcRdFiHRjhAuHcs05RI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.6.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-KsvD1yqQ1/1+IA7gi3P0tyJcT3vR+NdBTt13hSJ2lnve8agRGXTTyNaBYmCR/Nwi" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="/static/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Select2 JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/script.js"></script>
    
    
    <script>
        /*$('body').on('focus',".my-date-picker", function(){
            $('.my-date-picker').datetimepicker({
                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
                ignoreReadonly: true,
                showTodayButton: true
            });
        });*/
    </script>
    <script src="/static/formset/jquery.formset.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.formset_row').formset({
            addText: '<div style="color: #34C6AA;" class="my-2 text-center"><span class="oi oi-plus"></span> Add Education</div>',
            deleteText: '<div style="color: #f4816e; text-decoration: none;" class="my-2 text-center"> <span class="oi oi-x"></span> Remove Education</div> ',
            prefix: 'educations'
        });
    </script>



</body>
```

**EDIT1: As requested im sharing the code that uses the class formset**

```
{% extends '_base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load static %}



{% block content %}
</br>
    <h1 class="display-4 text-responsive">Edit your education information</h1>
<h3 class="display-6 text-muted">This will be visible on your profile</h3>
<p><span style="color: #f4816e;">IMPORTANT:</span></p>
<ul>
    <li>Leave the End Date field empty if you are currently enrolled in your school/university</li>
</ul>
<hr>    
<form method="POST" action=""> 
    {% csrf_token %} 

    {{ formset.management_form }} {# This is necessary when using formsets  #}
        {% for form in formset  %}
            
            {{ form.media }} {# This shit is responsible for showing the datepicker #}
            
            
            <div class="formset_row">
            <div class="row">
                    
                    {% if forloop.first %}
                            {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                                {{ hidden }}
                            {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}
                    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                        
                            {% if field.name == "start_date" or field.name == 'end_date' %}
                                {% if  field.name == 'end_date' %}
                                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-12 col-md-1">
                                        {{ field.label }} 
                                        {{ field }} </br>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                {% else %}
                                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-12 col-md-1">
                                        {{ field.label }}
                                        {{ field }} </br>
                                    </div>
                                {% endif %}
                            {% elif field.name != 'DELETE' %}
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                                    {{ field.label }}
                                    {{ field }} </br>
                                </div>
                            {% else %}
                                {{ field }}
                            {% endif %}
                        
                        
                    {% endfor %}
            </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    
    <div class="d-block d-sm-none ">
        <input type="submit" name="save_and_next" value="Save and continue to next step" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
        <input type="submit" name="save_and_profile"value="Save and go to profile" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-block">
        <a href="{% url 'recruitment:update_coach_prof_exp' %}" class="btn btn-light btn-block">Skip step</a>
    </div>
    <div class="d-none d-md-block ">
        <input type="submit" name="save_and_next" value="Save and continue to next step" class="btn btn-success">
        <input type="submit" name="save_and_profile"value="Save and go to profile" class="btn btn-outline-info">
        <a href="{% url 'recruitment:update_coach_prof_exp' %}" class="btn btn-light">Skip step</a>
    </div>

    
</form>
<script>
    $('body').on('focus',".my-date-picker", function(){
        $(this).datetimepicker({
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
            ignoreReadonly: true,
            showTodayButton: true
        });
    });
</script>
<script src="{% static 'formset/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.formset_row').formset({
        addText: '<div style="color: #34C6AA;" class="my-2 text-center"><span class="oi oi-plus"></span> Add Education</div>',
        deleteText: '<div style="color: #f4816e; text-decoration: none;" class="my-2 text-center"> <span class="oi oi-x"></span> Remove Education</div> ',
        prefix: '{{ formset.prefix }}'
    });
</script>
```

{% endblock content %}

**EDIT2: I added console.log(row) in the jquery plugin after insertDeleteLink = function(row) {**

[image]

**EDIT3 : Added content of line 76 (and above) from jquery plugin**
[image]

**FINAL EDIT**

[image]

In the end I solved the problem by looking up a more recent fork of the plugin and just replacing the whole code. Upon merging it I was able to find out that the difference was in the jquery plugin settings.

I literally know nothing about jquery and I can't really give an explanation on why earlier it didn't work and now it does. What I can say is that in the plugin settings'second row, when the `formTemplate` property was `$.data` it didn't work. Now it's `null` and it works.

**If someone can write here an explanation for myself and for others as to why this error appeared (and it kind of appeared out of nowhere) I will reward them the bounty.**

This problem caused me a lot of distress, and even though now i've overcome it and I feel great relief, I still would like to understand a little better what happened so that I won't be caught off guard next time. Also I believe that many others will benefit from it as this specific plugin is being used by hundreds if not thousands of Django websites all over the web.

Comment: can you show us the html of the element that has the class `formset_row` please

Comment: This didnt cause me any problem until yesterday. The crazy thing is that i tried restoring old commits and it still won't work.

Comment: Heyyyy.. uhh .. any news? This unsolvable error is overtaking my life

Comment: Looking at your template code, `<div class="formset_row">` is inserted into the template for each `form` in the `formset` context object. Because the javascript error says `'cannot read property ... of null'` this implies that jquery couldn't find any divs with class `formset_row`. Meaning that the `formset` object is empty. This is just a guess unless you can actually see your forms on the page

Comment: I can indeed see the form on the page!

Comment: I'm out of ideas at the moment sorry

Comment: Is that template code the entire template?

Comment: Now it's the whole template

Comment: Hi, can you do `console.log(row)` after this line `insertDeleteLink = function(row) {` see what its giving you .

Comment: I did as you asked and posted the resulting screenshot

Comment: Okay now which line is `76` inside `insertDeleteLink` ? can you point out that as well ?

Comment: Image added! I included the whole section

Comment: Your  code is calling your `insertDeleteLink` two times so for the first time its getting correct div but as you can see for the second console its not showing that div i think problem is there and as its not able to find `formrow_set` its giving you error .Can you check at your end if you have intialize `$('.formset_row').formset..` somewhere else as well ?

Comment: Heey i just realized that the first time it prints "ROW" on the console, the selector finds `#id_formset_row`. Shoudlnt that find `.formset_row instead`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230346/discussion-between-swati-and-beikeni).

Comment: I don't know if y'all received a notification when i updated the question. I've sort of accidentally solved the issue. I'm now offering the bounty to who can help me understand what happened.

Answer (score 1):

As you stated, setting the `formTemplate` property to null resulted in your form working.

From the docs of the plugin:

> `formTemplate`
>
> Use this to override the form that gets cloned, each time a new form
> instance is added. If specified, this should be a jQuery selector.

By setting this value, you overwrote your entire form element by loading a template. That's why you got the `Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of null` error, jQuery couldn't find the `.formset_row` element because you deleted it by overwriting it with the template. By setting the `formTemplate` property to `null`, the plugin was instructed to use the already present elements (aka. not overwriting the already present elements) and not a template (aka. overwriting the already present elements with the template).

I hope this cleared things up for you. :D